# Vowpal Wabbit Contextual Bandit Data Formatting

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have 2 questions about formatting data for contextual bandit model training.

If I have data such as below...

```
1:1:0.2 | d1:us d2:female d3:12
```

Question 1) I read from VW Wiki that each feature is optionally followed by a float. In case where I have categorical features (such as us, female) as values, what is the best way to re-format them? I am thinking that I would just not suffix them with a float let them have a default value of 1. I'm hoping this would achieve one-hot encoding.

Question 2) I've been wrongly training the model by logging the data as below

```
1:1:0.2 | us female 12
```

What I now realize is that "us", "female", and "12" are treated as features with default values as 1. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

The input feature format is: space-separated with each feature as `<name>:<value>` where `:<value>`, if present, must be numeric.

To represent categorical values you could use something other than `:` as separator between `<name>` and `<value>`.  In this case the whole string would be considered the feature name.  This is often called "one-hot encoding" (each possible feature+value combo is treated as a separate feature).

Also note that the feature name `12` will be hashed by `vw` directly to slot 12 (modulo 2^bits) in the hash table, assuming this is what the user wanted, since numeric features are common (and are the libSVM convention). This can be disabled by the option `--hash all` on the command line.  The default is `--hash strings` meaning: (murmur3) hash feature-names which look like a string (not an integer) but leave alone (don't hash) feature names that look like numbers.

See also: [***How to represent categorical features in vowpal-wabbit***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643968/1296044) which includes a cheat-sheet for representing input features in `vw`.