# How to use numerical features with Vowpal Wabbit?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, classification, vowpalwabbit

I'm a little bit confused with how vw input data is constructed; I want to have a numerical value in a vw namespace(without using `FeatureName` in `FeatureName:Float`, is it possible?), for example a line from my `train.txt`(file containing samples in vw format) in vw input format is something like this:

`1 |n 4.25522 |c good fair |s male`

Now I'm asking that does vw see the value inside the namespace `n` as a feature name and interpret it as something like `'4.25522':0.0`(`'4.25522'` i is the name of the feature and `0.0` is its value)? or it's used as a float value as it's being seen(a floating value number with 5 digits after the dot)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: I believe the answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643968/1296044 covers this.  You need to use:  FeatureName:FeatureValue  (i.e. a `:` separator, not a space between the name and value). This is orthogonal to whether you use name-spaces or not.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you are right about the format for encoding features(either numerical or categorical) in vw; I don't think think the two questions are quite identical because my question is more specific I suppose.